# StatusBar with timeout for messages implementation

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to implement a statusbar where i will be able to display messages for a specified period of time after which they will fadeout.

Can this be done with any ready made control in wpf? I can't find such a functionality in StatusBar which as far as i understand is a container of other items.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StatusBar` is indeed only a container of other items.
I think there isn't any built-in functionality like this.

But you can use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) to achieve what you want.

Make a method that sets the text message as the content of a `StatusBarItem`, set a time in the `Timer` and in the `Timer.Elapsed` event you remove the text from the `StatusBarItem`.

`StatusBar` XAML:

```
<StatusBar Height="25" Margin="5">
    <StatusBarItem x:Name="StatusMessage" />
</StatusBar>
```

Procedural code:

```
private void ShowStatusMessage(string message)
{
    StatusMessage.Content = message;
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 2000; //2 seconds
    timer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //stop the timer
        timer.Stop();
        //remove the StatusMessage text using a dispatcher, because timer operates in another thread
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            StatusMessage.Content = "";
        }));
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

If you want to animate you should look for [`DoubleAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Just bind the data in the progress bar and update it whenever faded out. Let us know more details for giving better solutions